# PHP bulk file read only list file in loop

Tags: php, loops, foreach, fread

php bulk file read problem in loop.

I have 3 image files which are already on server. Say it is picture1.jpg, picture2.jpg, picture3.jpg
I have this code which read the file but $thepic = fread($fh, $fs); only read last file ( picture3.jpg) in the array.

```
$imgfolder = "images/";


            foreach ($picturefile as  $pfile) {

                        echo $imgpath = "./". $imgfolder.$pfile; // This echo shows all files path when loop run

                        $picFile = $imgpath;
                        $fh = fopen($picFile, 'r');
                        $fs = filesize($picFile);
                        $thepic = fread($fh, $fs);
                        echo $thepic; // $thepic variable only show last file. 
                        echo "<br>-----------------------------------------------<br>"; 
                        fclose($fh);
            }
```

Comment: try to print $fh and $fs after the fopen to see whether the images arre returning anything or nit

Comment: $picFile  and $fh is giving result in every loop but $fs is only giving result in last loop. How to result for $fs in every loop iteration. ?